# How to write all the files names from a folder inside a txt file

Tags: powershell

With this code I get the data but is not reflected on the txt file. I just get a bunch of Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData.
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.GroupStartData
Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatEntryData

Instead the names of each file.

Here is the code:

```
   param(
[string]$foldername = 'unknown'
 )

 if (Test-Path $foldername){
$location = Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath "files.txt"
$files = Get-ChildItem $foldername | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer -ne $True} | Format-Table 
Name
$amount = Get-ChildItem $foldername | Where-Object {$_.PsIsContainer -ne $True} | Measure- 
Object
Add-Content -Path $location -Value $files
Write-Host $amount.count "filenames were written to file" $location
 }

else {Write-Host "Sorry,", $foldername, "does not exist."
break
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First `get-childitem` supports the switch `File`, no need to pipe and filter. The `Format-Table` is used to format the output displayed on the screen, so as you want to write to a file you do not need it.

Also only use `break` within a loop, if you want to stop the processing use `return` instead.

```
param(
    [string]$foldername = 'unknown'
)
    
if (Test-Path $foldername){
    $location = Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath "files.txt"
    #gets all files in the specified path
    $files = Get-ChildItem $foldername -File
    #counts the number of files
    $amount = $files.count
    #If you want the fullpath in the logfile use $files.fullname if you only want the name use $files.name
    $files.FullName | Add-Content -Path $location 
    Write-Host "$amount filenames were written to file $location"
}
else {
    Write-Host "Sorry, $foldername, does not exist."
    return
}
```

Comment: Thanks Toni for replying. I tried what u said but i got an error saying:

     "Join-Path : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument"

Comment: ```$location = Join-Path -Path $HOME -ChildPath "files.txt"``` = should work, at least it does on my machine.